# Any good website to find local companies and firms?

Tags: research, europe, business, social-media, email

I am looking for website catalogs of companies in Europe - Spain, Portugal, Baltic states, etc.

My knowledge of their native languages is very low, so I couldn't find any relevant results in English.

Could anyone please recommend such a website? For example - Czech Republic has firmy(dot)cz - something like yellow pages, but a local variant.

I am looking for websites and e-mails.